# How to call Method's Class Name dynamically?

Tags: c#, codec

Is it possible to use an input variable as a Method's Class Name?

---

**What I'm using now:**

`Switch`/`Case` with multiple `Namespace.Class.Method()`'s.

Each Codec Method is in its own Class.

```
public static void SetControls(string codec_SelectedItem)
{
    switch (codec_SelectedItem)
    {
        case "Vorbis":
            Codec.Vorbis.Set();
            break;

        case "Opus":
            Codec.Opus.Set();
            break;

        case "AAC":
            Codec.AAC.Set();
            break;

        case "FLAC":
            Codec.FLAC.Set();
            break;

        case "PCM":
            Codec.PCM.Set();
            break;
    }
}
```

---

**Trying to simplify:**

A single `Method` with a dynamic `Class`.
Use `SelectedItem` as Method's Class Name.

```
public static void SetControls(string codec_SelectedItem)
{
    Codec.[codec_SelectedItem].Set(); 
}
```

Comment: I doubt this code compiles

Comment: A dictionary of codec names & an interface implementing .set() ?

Comment: @WalterVehoeven Correct, the second example doesn't compile. I'm trying to find the correct way if it's possible.

Comment: _"you can use reflexion"_ @OlivierRogier _why_?? It's utterly unnecessary. Just apply some OOP.

Comment: Are Codecs nested Classes in "Codec"? What's that structure, looks like they are static classes?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, the classes `Vorbis`, `AAC`, etc, are nested under the `Codec` namespace. It was not static, but works either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a dictionary with instances of the differenct codecs, initialize the dictionary a single time with all codecs. And then get any codec by name whenever you need it.  Each codec must be a separate non-static class implementing a ICodec interface you create.

Example, unvalidated c#, to give you the gist:

```
private static Dictionary<string, ICodec> _codec;

public static void Initialize()
{
    _codec = new Dictionary<string, ICodec> { 
        { "Vorbis", new VorbisCodec() }
        { "Opus", new OpusCodec() }
    };
}

public static void SetControls(string codecName)
{
    _codec[codecName].set();
}

public interface ICodec
{
    void set();
}
```

Addition as you commented to have it even more compact:

You can also use reflection to get a class by name, instantiate it and then call the .set() method:

```
((ICodec) Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(codecClassNameHere))).set();
```

I advise against it though. Code should also be readable. The Dictionary approach shows very cleanly what's going on. Reflection hides that, this is often more annoying for maintaining the code later on, than the "coolness" of making it very compact with reflection now :)

Comment: This would work, but I don't know if it's simplifying it any more than the switch/case.

Comment: Often, this kind of switch case stuff is put in a factory class. CodecFactory.Create(codecName) then returns an ICodec, with which you can do your thing. This way the ugliness of the case is hidden in a single place, and you use clean single-line calls to ICodec everywhere else

Comment: I'm working on implementing it, I will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Where it says `{ Vorbis", new VorbisCodec() }`, I'm not sure what `VorbisCodec()` is referring to.

Comment: I changed it to `{ "Vorbis", new Codec.Vorbis() }`, I get the error `Cannot convert from 'Controls.Audio.Codec.Vorbis' to 'Controls.Audio.Controls.ICodec'`.

Comment: ICodec is an interface that all your codecs must implement. so Codec.Vorbis must implement ICodec. To do this, the definition of Vorbis must read "public class Vorbis : ICodec".  This will force the Vorbis to implement the "contract" defined by ICodec. (maybe google a bit about C# interfaces for more info) Otherwise you're on the right track.

Comment: It looks to be working, I will do some more testing. It simplified about 300 lines of `switch`/`case` down to about 40 lines with `ICodec` `interface`. Now if I add a new codec, I can just update the `Dictionary` instead of adding a new `case` with methods. https://pastebin.com/raw/y2046uzP

Comment: i advise to put ICodec in a separate file. and in setcontrols() you can create a variable "var selectedCodec = _codec[codec_SelectedItem]" and reuse the variable in all those similar lines of code in that method. thats prettier

Comment: I have a related question for you https://stackoverflow.com/q/65204994/6806643