# interface List Error "does not implement interface member"

Tags: c#

I'm expanding on my previous question, which was solved. [How to call Method's Class Name dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65182202/6806643)

`interface IVideoCodec` works with `void` Methods successfully, but it is not working with `List`.

`VP8` `Class` gives the error `'VP8' does not implement interface member 'Controls.IVideoCodec.test'`

[image: VP8 Class Error]

---

File: VideoControls.cs

```
namespace Controls.Video
{
    public class Controls
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, IVideoCodec> _vCodecClass;

        private static void InitializeCodecs()
        {
            _vCodecClass = new Dictionary<string, IVideoCodec> {
                { "VP8",  new Codec.VP8() },
                { "VP9",  new Codec.VP9() },
                { "x264", new Codec.x264() },
                { "x265", new Codec.x265() }
            };
        }

        public interface IVideoCodec
        {
            List<string> test { get; set; } // doesn't work

            //void Example(); // works
        }

        public static void SetControls(string codec_SelectedItem)
        {
            InitializeCodecs();

            List<string> example = _vCodecClass[codec_SelectedItem].test; // equal to Codec.VP8.test

            //_vCodecClass[codec_SelectedItem].Example(); // equal to Codec.VP8.Example() // works
        }
    }
}
```

File: VP8.cs

```
namespace Controls.Video.Codec
{
    public class VP8 : Controls.IVideoCodec // <-- Gives Error
    {
        public List<string> test = new List<string>()
        {
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
        };

        public void Example()
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've defined `test` as a field not a property in your `VP8` class..

Comment: You need `test => new`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your interface you declare a property but in VP8 you have a field. Change it to

```
public class VP8 : Controls.IVideoCodec // <-- Gives Error
{
    public List<string> test  {get; set;} = new List<string>()
    {
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    };

    public void Example()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error. I need to do some more testing and I'll get back to you and mark as solved.